# How do you change the default settings in Wordpad file?

Tags: windows, settings

I have a Windows Wordpad (.RTF) file document that contains Website link like; www.domainname.com. Whenever I click on these links it automatically opens up on IE Explorer browser. How do I change the default link settings so that it automatically opens up with Mozilla Firefox instead of IE Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default settings and to enable Mozilla Firefox to open Wordpad`s HTTP links:

Open Mozilla Firefox ->go to: Tools ->click on: Options, then Follow the Green highlighted regions on the snapshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]